# Need to disable tap to share wifi password in android

Tags: android, wifi, password-protection

I am developing an app to connect to specific WiFi network. It works fine, but  after connecting to the network a user can share WiFi password by tapping on the connected network name through QR code. Its a nice feature, yet it is a security threat because a user who is connected to the network can share the password to others. I think there should have an option to turn off this mechanism but I did not find any. 
So, I decided to design my app to be able to disable tap to share option or hide the connected network name form WiFi list. I just want to protect users from sharing WiFi password with others. Any help?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?